# Conditional formatting with xlsx writer generates corrupt file with "text:containing"

Tags: python, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

So I have some code that applies conditional formatting to an Excel file based on cell values.  I wanted to add some to the same range based on the "text" type using the criteria "containing".  These columns are filled with strings of dates, and I wanted to apply a format to dates that contain "2017".

Here's the whole block, and it works fine with conditional formatting of the cells if I comment out the conditional formatting for the text:

```
mtbook = mytrials_writer.book
header_format = mtbook.add_format({'bg_color': '#7e98f7','bold': True})
notFoundFormat = sitebook.add_format({'bg_color':'red'})
notExpFormat = sitebook.add_format({'bg_color':'silver'})
foundFormat = sitebook.add_format({'bg_color':'lime'})
for worksheet in mtbook.worksheets():
    # for every column
    for i in range(len(subreportCols)):
        # write the value of the first cell in the column to the first cell of that column
        worksheet.write(0, i, subreportCols[i], header_format)
        worksheet.set_column(0, 50, 17)
        worksheet.set_row(0, 25, None)
        worksheet.conditional_format('A2:Z100', {'type':'text', 'criteria': 'containing', 'value':'2017','format':notFoundFormat})
        #worksheet.conditional_format('A2:Z100', {'type':'text', 'criteria': 'containing', 'value':'"2016-"','format':foundFormat})
        #worksheet.conditional_format('A2:Z100', {'type':'text', 'criteria': 'containing', 'value':'"2015-"','format':foundFormat})
        worksheet.conditional_format('A2:Z100', {'type':'cell', 'criteria': '==', 'value':'"Miss/Inc"','format':notFoundFormat})
        worksheet.conditional_format('A2:Z100', {'type':'cell', 'criteria': '==', 'value':'"NotExp."','format':notExpFormat})
```

If I enable the lines like the following, the code will run, but the Excel file will open, ask if I want to repair because it's corrupt; if I say yes, then there's no formatting anywhere in the doc.

```
worksheet.conditional_format('A2:Z100', {'type':'text', 'criteria': 'containing', 'value':'2017','format':notFoundFormat})
```

The error says, "We found a problem with some content in FILE.  Do you want to try and recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes"

This is the error log that is returned:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<recoveryLog xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/spreadsheetml/2006/main"><logFileName>error255040_01.xml</logFileName><summary>Errors were detected in file 'C:\Users\mgancsos\Documents\Data Sources\Python\Testing\TQ_MyTrials_upload.xlsx'</summary><repairedRecords><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml part</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet2.xml part</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet3.xml part</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet4.xml part</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet5.xml part</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet6.xml part</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet7.xml part</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet8.xml part</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet9.xml part</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet10.xml part</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet11.xml part</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet12.xml part</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: Conditional formatting from /xl/worksheets/sheet13.xml part</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: C</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: C</repairedRecord><repairedRecord>Repaired Records: C</repairedRecord><repairedRecord xml:space="preserve">Repaired Records: </repairedRecord></repairedRecords></recoveryLog>
```

Thank you!

Comment: not sure why you use 'text' if 'cell' works. Sounds like the one failing is a date, so did you try using 'date' type?

Comment: "Containing" is not something listed for "cell", only for "text".  
http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_conditional_formats.html?highlight=conditional

Comment: did you try date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is the double quotes around the string you want to match. Try this instead:

```
worksheet.conditional_format('A2:Z100', 
    {'type': 'text', 
     'criteria': 'containing', 
     'value':'2016-',
     'format': foundFormat})
```

Comment: This solved it.  Earlier code that I had didn't work, and while looking for solutions, I read in another post that the double-quotes were necessary.  After a few other tries, I ended up with this, but retained the double quotes.  Taking them out fixed this.  Thank you!!!